# How to increase a number in a string that also contains letters?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I want to perform arithmetic operations on numbers in a string.

For example: `SGJKR67` should become `SGJKR68`.

Another one: `NYSC34` should become `NYSC35`.

Only numbers are changed, in this example both are increased by one.

Comment: Are the numbers always in the end, or sometimes between letters too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex and Capturing Groups can solve your problem:

```
$reg = [regex]::new("([A-Z]+)(\d+)")
$m = $reg.Match("SGJKR67")
$digits = $m.Groups[2] # will be 67
$digits = $digit + 1; # or apply anything you want
$result = "$($m.Groups[1])$digits" # will be SGJKR and 68.
```

You will have 3 groups for your matches:

- The whole "word".
- The letters
- the digits.

Comment: Try with `$digits = $m.Groups[2].Value -as [int]` and `$digits = $digits + 1`

Answer (score 1):

**In PowerShell *Core* (v6.1+)**, you can use the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

- with a [*regex* (regular expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) for *matching* the embedded numbers

  - `\d+` is a sequence of one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`)
- and a [*script block* (`{ ... }`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) as the replacement operand, which allows you to dynamically determine replacement strings on a per-match basis:

  - Inside the script block, which is called for every match, [automatic variable `$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#_) contains a [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance with information about the match at hand; in the simplest case, `$_.Value` returns the matched text.

```
PS> 'SGJKR67', 'NYSC34' -replace '\d+', { 1 + [int] $_.Value }

SGJKR68
NYSC35
```

---

**In *Windows PowerShell***, where script-block replacement operands aren't supported, you must use the .NET `[regex]` type's static [`.Replace()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) directly:

```
PS> 'SGJKR67', 'NYSC34' | ForEach-Object {
      [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { param($m) 1 + [int] $m.Value })
    }

SGJKR68
NYSC35
```

<sup>Note: Unlike `-replace`, `[regex]::Match()` doesn't support passing an *array* of input strings, hence the use of a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call; inside *its* script block (`{ ... }`), `$_` refers to the *input string* at hand.</sup>

The approach is fundamentally the same, except that the match at hand (the `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` instance) is passed as an *argument* to the script block, which parameter declaration `param($m)` captures in variable `$m`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the numbers from the string, calculate the new number and return everything as string.

```
[System.String]$NumberInString = 'SGJKR68'
[System.String]$String = $NumberInString.Substring(0, 5)
[System.Int32]$Int = $NumberInString.Substring(5, 2)
$Int += 1
[System.String]$NewNumberInString = ($String + $Int)
$NewNumberInString
```