# How can a captured string from -replace be changed to uppercase int the result?

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a database type string of `varchar(30)`, I would like to standardize it for SQL Server by capitalizing the type name and putting it in brackets. The desired result is `[VARCHAR](30)`.

How can I convert $1 to uppercase? This expression identifies the type and adds brackets, but is does not ToUpper().

```
PS> "varchar(30)" -replace '^\[*(\w+)\]*(.*)','[$1]$2'
[varchar](30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simplified version of your regex:

In **PowerShell [Core] v6.1+**:

```
PSCore> 'varchar(30)' -replace '^\[*\w+\]*', { '[' + $_.Value.ToUpper() + ']' }
[VARCHAR](30)
```

<sup>Note: If there can be *at most* one `[...]` enclosure in the input, `\[?` and `\]?` should be used instead.</sup>

In **Windows PowerShell**:

```
WinPS> [regex]::Replace('varchar(30)', '^\[*\w+\]*', { param($m) '[' + $m.Value.ToUpper() + ']' })
[VARCHAR](30)
```

For background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58608437/45375).

Answer (score 0):

here is a very slightly different way that uses the `$Matches` automatic variable and the `-f` string format operator. [*grin*]

it makes a few presumptions about the input data, but not as serious as presuming `varchar` is the only word you want to convert to all-caps. those are ...

- the stuff you want as ALLCAPS is everything up to the 1st `(`
- the remainder is to be kept as is
- the 1st part is to be enclosed in brackets `[]`

the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
varchar(30)
OtherThing(21)
santa(666)
ALREADYALLCAPS(97531)
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match '(.+)(\(.+)'
    '[{0}]{1}' -f $Matches[1].ToUpper(), $Matches[2]
    }
```

output ...

```
[VARCHAR](30)
[OTHERTHING](21)
[SANTA](666)
[ALREADYALLCAPS](97531)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lee_Dailey. I was using $Matches before after doing a `-match` operation. I forgot that I could just produce the string from $Matches, so I was repeating the regex in a `-replace`.

Comment: @lit - you are most welcome! [*grin*] i tried to use `-replace` and gave up since i wanted to manipulate things without too many awkward steps. [*grin*]