# How do I use variables with the -replace Operator?

Tags: powershell

I'm rather new to powershell, and I have been trying to make a script that takes all files in a directory with numbers in the title and renames them according to a template.

My Script looks like such:

```
$NewObjName = "My New Name"

cd E:\Test

dir | ren -NewName {$_.name -replace '([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])\.(\d?)(\d).*','0$3$4'}
dir | ren -NewName {$_.name -replace '(\d?)(\d)(\d)',{Part $2$3 $NewObjName.txt}}
```

and does this:

```
PS E:\Test> ls


    Directory: E:\Test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                            
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                            
-a----          8/1/2022   2:14 PM              0 AB.01CDE                                                                                                                                        
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 AB.02CDE                                                                                                                                        
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 AB.10CDE                                                                                                                                        
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 AB.11CDE                                                                                                                                        



PS E:\Test> E:\RenameScript.ps1

PS E:\Test> ls


    Directory: E:\Test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                            
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                            
-a----          8/1/2022   2:14 PM              0 Part 01 $NewObjName.txt                                                                                                                         
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 Part 02 $NewObjName.txt                                                                                                                         
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 Part 10 $NewObjName.txt                                                                                                                         
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 Part 11 $NewObjName.txt                                                                                                                         



PS E:\Test>
```

So it just puts in the variable name instead of the value of the variable.
I'm not sure if `-replace` doesn't allow variables other than regex groupings or if I'm just missing something?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:
My expected result would be something like:

```
PS E:\Test> ls


    Directory: E:\Test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                            
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                            
-a----          8/1/2022   2:14 PM              0 Part 01 My New Name.txt                                                                                                                         
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 Part 02 My New Name.txt                                                                                                                         
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 Part 10 My New Name.txt                                                                                                                         
-a----          8/1/2022   2:15 PM              0 Part 11 My New Name.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show what you’re trying to end up with.

Comment: Please show the expected result, and use double-quotes as well: `'(\d?)(\d)(\d)',"Part $2$3 $NewObjName.txt"`.

Comment: I added the expected results, also I tried changing to double quotes and now I'm not really sure what it's doing tbh. This is my first powershell project so I'm quite unfamiliar with the workings of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$_.name -replace '(\d?)(\d)(\d)',{Part $2$3 $NewObjName.txt}`

- `{ ... }` is a [*script-block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) literal, not a *string* literal.

  - When a script block is used in a context where it is coerced to a string, such as in your case, its *verbatim content* (sans `{` and `}`) is used. Therefore, `$NewObjName` was *not* expanded (interpolated).

    - While it can be convenient to use `{ ... }` in lieu of an actual string literal in order to avoid the need for escaping of embedded quoting, it is best avoided in the interest of conceptual clarity.
  - As an aside: In *PowerShell (Core) 6.1+*, script blocks *are* now supported as the replacement operand of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator, albeit *as script blocks*, i.e. they provide a piece of code to run for a each match in order to dynamically determine the replacement text - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58608437/45375) for an example.
- Since you need string *expansion* (interpolation), you must specify your replacement operand as an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)

  - However, `$2` and `$3` - even tough they look like PowerShell variables - are actually placeholders for what the regex operation matched, and therefore must be *passed through* to the .NET regex engine.
  - To that end (to prevent up-front expansion by PowerShell), they must be escaped as `` `$2 `` and `` `$3 ``, using `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).
  - Note:

    - If you use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) - which is the best choice if interpolation is *not* needed - placeholders such as `$2` and `$3` can be used as-is.
    - As an alternative to the expandable string solution below, you can conceptually separate the aspect of up-front expansion and the verbatim string to pass to the .NET regex engine via `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f):

      ```bash
      # Same as: "Part `$2`$3 $NewObjName.txt"
      ('Part $2$3 {0}.txt' -f $NewObjName)
      ```

Therefore:

```bash
$_.name -replace '(\d?)(\d)(\d)', "Part `$2`$3 $NewObjName.txt"
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that $2 and $3 needed to be escaped! Thank you for your assistance. This answered my question perfectly, and helped me learn several new things! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Loger42; my pleasure.

Comment: Only need to be escaped in double quotes, single quotes they are fine

Comment: @DougMaurer good point in general, I've added it to the answer. Note that in this particular case double quotes are a must due to the need to expand `$NewObjectName` - if you want to use just a string literal, that is. I've also added an alternative with `-f`.

Comment: @Loger42, please also see the update to the answer.