# Increment Numbers in an Unknown Substring by One

Tags: string, powershell, increment

I need to get the name of the last file that was copied and then increment by one to get the next file. The files follow the pattern DDMM###.TXT where ### will start with 000 and end with 005 for the day.
I know I can use substring to get the ###, and then increment by 1, and then used replace to replace the ### with the new incremented "string". I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this.

```
    $value = $filetotransfer.substring(4,3)
    $newvalue = ([int]$value+1).ToString('000')
    $filetotransfer = $filetotransfer.Replace($value,$newvalue)
```

Where $filetotransfer can be mmdd000.txt to mmdd005.txt depending on the time of the day.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

  ```bash
  # -> '0506001.txt'
  '0506000.txt' -replace '(?<=^\d{4})...', { '{0:000}' -f (1 + $_.Value) }
  ```
- In *Windows PowerShell*, the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) doesn't support script blocks (`{ ... }`) as the replacement operand, which makes the solution more complex, because a direct call to the underlying .NET API is required:

  ```bash
  # -> '0506001.txt'
  [regex]::Replace('0506000.txt', '(?<=^\d{4})...', { param($m) '{0:000}' -f (1 + $m.Value) })
  ```

For an explanation of these techniques, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58602659/45375).